# Zathura's best-fit command ('a') for documents with varying page size

Tags: zathura, documents

I'm usually using the wonderful document viewer 'zathura' for reading PDF-files. Typically, for some documents, the first page of the document is slightly larger than the rest (for example, a photograph of a book cover). In this case the 'best-fit' function (key 'a') of zathura always adjusts the zoom relative to the first page of the document, implying that for the rest of the document the pages are displayed smaller than they should be. This is particularly annoying when reading documents in 'double-page mode', leading to results as terrible as the following:
[image]

**My Question:** Is there any way to change this behaviour such that the 'best-fit' function adjusts the size relative to the currently viewed page?

Comment: Zathura uses the max-width of all pages for its best fit, which is really annoying on variable-width pdfs... We should probably fill a feature-request or bug report